# Can you make a plain background without using HTML Text?

Tags: html, css

i started working on some CSS Project and i'm wondering how can i colour in a background without needing any text...I've tried using an empty div and that wouldn't make a background (like a bar, not the complete background.) I'd have to insert some random text in to be able to make it a strip of color on the page.

```html
<style>
  #bg {
    background-color: yellow
  }
</style>

<div id="bg">
  <p>somehting</p>
</div>
```

This is pretty much how my code would go down, i'd need some sort of text to make a background of. But i want just to make a background without needing any text, like a completely empty strip across the page. Any inputs? Thanks.

Comment: why don't you try adding some width and height to the div..!!! Then the background color would apply to the div without any text.

Comment: Still nothing. the code still goes down like this now                                <style>
#something{
width:100px
background-color:blue
height:500px;}                                                                                                                                 <body>
 <div id="something"></div>
                                                   Still doesn't work and i don't know why

Comment: So, basically you need a bar covering the whole width of browser, and small height? Is that the problem???

Comment: @NewbButLearnin Both the answers  will work with or without `p` inside

Answer (score 1):

Set a `width` and `height` for your element. By default, the width and height is not set and hence the browser does not know how much space to take for the background-color to be applied. After adding content, the browser is able to generate the paint bound/drawable area.

```css
#bg {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a with and height to your `#bg`.

For example:

```
<style> 
  #bg{background-color:yellow; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
</style>

<body> 
<div id="bg">
</div>
```

Comment: I removed the `<p>`  from my answer.. should work the same with or without it though

Answer (score 0):

you will need to set width and height into your div because by default a div size is as big as the content inside(default width and height are `auto`), so if your div has no content then it will collapse as expected. likewise, you can also set width/height to set the div default size so it will not collapse.